# Setup correctly Qmake on Windows 10

Tags: windows, qt

My adventure in the world of QT and multi-platform continue, with another roadblock.

I am on Windows 10 now; I did install QT5 and I was able to run one of the examples, so I thought everything is fine. Instead, when trying to build PythonQt, I get an error from qmake:

`Project ERROR: Cannot run compiler 'cl'. Maybe you forgot to setup the environment?`

I thought myself; that there is something missing; although had no luck finding what the heck do I have to actually do to set up qmake. I did assume that when you install QT, everything get set up for you, but instead it seems that something is missing.

I am on W10, using the latest installer for Python 2.7 (it is working, since when I call `python` I get correctly the interpreter to launch); am I missing something else?

Comment: It is about MS C++ compiler. Follow this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ccy3wt.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the info; I did read that page although I was not able to get the connection with my case.
Then I did realize that I was using an incorrect version of the tools. For some reason, Qt 5 did not like my VS2015 version; but once I removed that and installed VS2017, it is now able to run qmake. The issue with that `cl` message is still happening but only if I run qmake in the folder to build PythonQt, so I just let it go and used something different. Thanks!

Comment: You need to know that the specific Qt you use in the project (Project Settings in Qt Creator) was compiled with specific version of C++ compiler and enable that.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue with Qt5.9.1 and VS2015. I fixed this by editing "C:\Qt\Qt5.9.1\5.9.1\msvc2015\bin\qtenv2.bat" file. I added below 2 lines.

> call "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"
>
> Start ""  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"

And then run the "Qt 5.9.1 32-bit for Desktop (MSVC 2015)" ( or 64 bit depends on your choice.).

This would set the environment before running the qmake.
Calling the vcvarsall.bat fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to [@PrimeOfKnights 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46350722/987846) for the sake of completeness:

with VS2017 community, the location of `vcvarsall.bat` is

```
/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Auxiliary/Build/vcvarsall.bat
```

In `qtenv2.bat`, it actually says:

```
echo Remember to call vcvarsall.bat to complete environment setup!
```